# Run SimpleArcApp from sankey-arcs

Tags: java, eclipse

I found a project on github called sankey-arcs from Till Nagel. Because I'm interested in drawing sankey diagrams consisting of lots of nodes I thought a java based application would be more helpfull.

While searching a bit through the files in the sankey-arcs project I saw that this is created with the IDE Eclipse. So I installed eclipse and cloned the project from github. Now I need to find out how to use the applications.

I found in the src/com/tillnagel/geom/arcs/apps a java file SimpleArcApp.java which I'm trying to run, but without any luck.

The message I get when running the SimpleArcApp.java: Can't load library: C:\workspace\sankey-arcs\gluegen-rt.dll

With a bit of help of Google it's possible to find some hints, but I don't get it right. There is a lib folder in the project with "gluegen-rt.jar, which should probably included somehow.

Does anybody has a hint how I can get this application to run?
Any help is appriciated.

Comment: Project owner, here. Are you trying to run it on a Windows machine? The gluegen-rt is a OpenGL library, and yes, you need to point Eclipse to the native implementation (i.e. the dll) file. In the github project I included the version for Mac OS only - so you need to download it from http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Downloading_and_installing_JOGL and install it yourself.

Comment: I'm indeed trying to run on a windows machine. I will try to install jogl. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I face another challenge to get the app running. Now the exception: Failed to find NEWT Display Class is shown. Any ideas?